# Create and position Hole

Tags: vba, solidworks

i'm trying to write a macro that can create a hole into a simple block. You should be able to determine the diameter of the hole and its position.

I have this code for example, where it will locate the Hole exactly where I selected the face. Is there a possibility to define the exact location of the hole, like with an x and y value? So that I dont have to select the face by myself.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ErstelleBohrung()
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swFeat As SldWorks.Feature
    Dim swFeatMgr As SldWorks.FeatureManager
    
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

    Set swFeatMgr = swModel.FeatureManager
    Set swFeat = swFeatMgr.HoleWizard5(swWzdCounterSink, swStandardAnsiMetric, swStandardAnsiMetricFlatHead82, "M2", swEndCondThroughAll, 0.0102, 0.010312189893273, 0, 0.0044, 1.57079632679489, 1.52189893272978E-04, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, "", False, True, True, True, True, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you ran into when you attempted it?

Comment: ok I edited my question, I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a face at a specific point using `IModelDocExtension.SelectByID2`. An example is given below (specify your own values for `xCoord`, `yCoord` and `zCoord`):

```
Dim selected as Boolean
selected = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2("", "FACE", xCoord, yCoord, zCoord, True, 0, Nothing, swSelectOption_e.swSelectOptionDefault)
```

Selecting a face at an exact point often isn't that useful when automating (normally we want some form of basic user input). One option would be to allow a user to select a sketch containing a point(s) on a face and use those coordinates to make the selection call above. In face, SolidWorks actually provide an example doing just this in their [help docs](https://help.solidworks.com/2023/english/api/sldworksapi/create_holes_using_hole_wizard_and_sketch_points_example_vb.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I saw that example, however in my scenario the number of holes can vary, making that example not very useful because the user would have to create the sketch manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I'm happy with:

```
Option Explicit
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Dim startPointX As Double
Dim startPointY As Double
Dim startPointZ As Double
Dim rayVecX As Double
Dim rayVecY As Double
Dim rayVecZ As Double
Dim radius As Double
Dim status As Boolean

Sub main()
   
   Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
   Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
   Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension
   startPointX = -1
   startPointY = 0.05
   startPointZ = 0
   rayVecX = 0#
   rayVecY = 0#
   rayVecZ = -1#
   radius = 3#
   status = swModelDocExt.SelectByRay(startPointX, startPointY, startPointZ, rayVecX, rayVecY, rayVecZ, radius, swSelectType_e.swSelFACES, False, 0, swSelectOption_e.swSelectOptionDefault)
   Debug.Print "Selection status: " & status
   Set swFeatMgr = swModel.FeatureManager
   Set swFeat = swFeatMgr.HoleWizard5(swWzdCounterSink, swStandardAnsiMetric, swStandardAnsiMetricFlatHead82, "M2", swEndCondThroughAll, 0.0102, 0.010312189893273, 0, 0.0044, 1.57079632679489, 1.52189893272978E-04, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, "", False, True, True, True, True, False)
   
End Sub
```

That way i can position the hole on a face in x and y coordinates, it will create the hole where the ray crosses the face. It works for me because it´s always the same face. I will probably put that in some kind of loop so the number of holes can vary.